# Vue and TinyMCE Issue

Tags: vue.js, tinymce, vue-component

I am trying to integrate a [TinyMCE](https://tiny.cloud) editor into my Vue application. From the Developer Tools Console I am able to access the tinymce object and manipulate it. For example:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setContent('I am a replacement')
```

The above code will replace the selected text within the TinyMCE editor. I want to work with the tinymce object from within Vue (in multiple components) but I am not sure how to access it. The exact error I get when I enter the above code into a function is: **error  'tinymce' is not defined  no-undef**.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any code at all it is hard to say exactly why this is happening. Documenting how you are instantiating TinyMCE would help.

Based on the error message I would assume that you are using the TinyMCE Vue component/wrapper to inject TinyMCE into your Vue component.  By default that does not actually load the core TinyMCE editor until run-time - and at that time it loads thing via the TinyMCE Cloud server.

The error you are seeing is your linting tool (`eslint`?) complaining that you are trying to call a variable `tinymce` but that variable is not defined anywhere.

There are a few ways you could choose to "fix" `eslint` complaining:

1 - Access `tinymce` through the global window object:

```
window.tinymce
```

2 - Wrap your code with a directive for eslint to not check for undefined variables:

```
/*eslint-disable no-undef*/
...
/*eslint-enable no-undef*/
```

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments

3 - Define a global in your `.eslintrc` file

```
{
  "globals": {
    "tinymce": true
  }
}
```

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. With the information you provided, I was able to find a solution. I added "tinymce": true to globals in package.json under "eslintConfig". The error is no longer thrown by the linter. Thanks again.

Comment: If that worked can you mark this answer correct so others don't spend time trying to address this question?  Thanks.